# Matlab error in Backpropagation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Here is a matalab program for backpropagation algorithm-

```
% XOR input for x1 and x2
input = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1];
% Desired output of XOR
output = [0;1;1;0];
% Initialize the bias
bias = [-1 -1 -1];
% Learning coefficient
coeff = 0.7;
% Number of learning iterations
iterations = 10000;
% Calculate weights randomly using seed.
rand('state',sum(100.*clock));
weights = -1 +2.*rand(3,3);

for i = 1:iterations
   out = zeros(4,1);
   numIn = length (input(:,1));
   for j = 1:numIn
      % Hidden layer
      H1 = bias(1,1).*weights(1,1) + input(j,1).*weights(1,2)+ input(j,2).*weights(1,3);

      % Send data through sigmoid function 1/1+e^-x
      % Note that sigma is a different m file 
      % that I created to run this operation
      x2(1) = sigma(H1);
      H2 = bias(1,2).*weights(2,1)+ input(j,1).*weights(2,2)+ input(j,2).*weights(2,3);
      x2(2) = sigma(H2);

      % Output layer
      x3_1 = bias(1,3).*weights(3,1)+ x2(1).*weights(3,2)+ x2(2).*weights(3,3);
      out(j) = sigma(x3_1);

      % Adjust delta values of weights
      % For output layer:
      % delta(wi) = xi*delta,
      % delta = (1-actual output)*(desired output - actual output) 
      delta3_1 = out(j).*(1-out(j)).*(output(j)-out(j));

      % Propagate the delta backwards into hidden layers
      delta2_1 = x2(1).*(1-x2(1)).*weights(3,2).*delta3_1;
      delta2_2 = x2(2).*(1-x2(2)).*weights(3,3).*delta3_1;

      % Add weight changes to original weights 
      % And use the new weights to repeat process.
      % delta weight = coeff*x*delta
      for k = 1:3
         if k == 1 % Bias cases
            weights(1,k) = weights(1,k) + coeff.*bias(1,1).*delta2_1;
            weights(2,k) = weights(2,k) + coeff.*bias(1,2).*delta2_2;
            weights(3,k) = weights(3,k) + coeff.*bias(1,3).*delta3_1;
         else % When k=2 or 3 input cases to neurons
            weights(1,k) = weights(1,k) + coeff.*input(j,1).*delta2_1;
            weights(2,k) = weights(2,k) + coeff.*input(j,2).*delta2_2;
            weights(3,k) = weights(3,k) + coeff.*x2(k-1).*delta3_1;
         end
      end
   end   
end
```

But its showing error like -

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> sigma at 95
  a=varargin{1}; b=varargin{2}; c=varargin{3}; d=varargin{4};

Error in ==> back at 25
      x2(1) = sigma(H1);
```

Please help me out. I am not able to understand the problem. Why there is an error saying index exceeds matrix dimension? Help is needed.

Comment: You are not passing 4 arguments to `sigma`, if it is a function.

Comment: I suggest you read up on MATLAB's debugging tools: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html